# read JSON object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object:

```
"Master": {
                "nodeType": "Test",
                "label": "Master",
                "nodes": {
                    "event": {
                        "nodeType": "Test",
                        "label": "Test",
                        "itemTemplate": {
                            "label": "Test",
                            "properties": {
                                "icon": {
                                    "label": "Test",
                                    "description": "Test",
                                    "valueType": "STRING",
                                    "value": ""
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "icon": "test 2",
                            },
                            {
                                "icon": "test 1",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

I want to access the `items` section. I've tried the following:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_object); //json object
alert(obj.nodes.items[0].icon); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Comment: Make sure you have valid json, you could try this: http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items;
items = obj.Master.nodes.event.items;

alert(items[0].icon);
```

`items` result in an array

note your json is incorrect as is missing a leading { and two trailing }

```
json_object = '{ "Master": {

//
//
//

} }';
```

If not correct `jQuery.parseJSON` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON defines a single key called "Master".  Try:

```
alert(obj.Master.nodes.items[0].icon);
```

Comment: @free4ride got it right - items is under nodes' event key.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(obj.Master.nodes.event.items[0].icon)
```

check structure of your json here : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

[image]

that will help you to understand node inheritance

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(obj.Master.nodes.event.items[0].icon);
```

and validate your json
http://jsonlint.com/